# Instagram API OAuth from native app

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, oauth, instagram

Currently, I'm getting the access token by requesting Instagram's OAuth via this:

```
//Create OAuth
NSString *oAuthURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=%@&redirect_uri=%@&response_type=token", instagramID, instagramRedirectUri];

self.authWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 64.0f, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:oAuthURL];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[self.authWebView loadRequest:requestObj];
self.authWebView.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:self.authWebView];
```

However, I would like to be able to launch the native Instagram app (if available) to something similar like the facebook app's single sign on. Is this possible? It'd be pretty cool if the instagram app just asks for permission and the user presses ok instead of filling in their credentials.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instagram doesn't have any support for this currently, unfortunately. It's something that needs to be supported in the app itself.